# Array data types in an Angular 2 model form

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm creating a data-driven form where the user can select multiple options. So I set toggable buttons like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6JEa.png) but I'm not able to set my FormBuilder object (see complications attribute below) with the selected options.

```
        this.consultForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        visit: this.formBuilder.group({
            date: ["12-12-2010", Validators.required],
            signature: ["test", Validators.required]
        }),
        eva: this.formBuilder.group({
            rest: ["1", Validators.required],
            tmd: ["1", Validators.required]
        }),
        sos: ["1", Validators.required],
        complications: this.formBuilder.array(["teste", "2"]),
        observations:"",
        satisfaction: ["Good", Validators.required],
        discharge: ""
    });
```

I'm using [telerik's framework](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/buttongroup/) btw

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ButtonGroup` component does not implement ***ControlValueAccessor***, which is required to wire-up component with angular forms. It has never been intended to act as a form component.

Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a way to implement CheckboxControlValueAccessor but an alternative was to call a method in my component which modifies the formbuilder. The problem is that somehow this calls my ngSubmit function. If I resolve this I'll update this thread

Comment: Can you share some runnable code in the form of plnkr? I might be able to assist you.

Comment: I wasn't able to create a funcional example (I'll try to fix it when i have time) but I think it presents the problem correctly. http://plnkr.co/edit/GkdJJ7zQKIHX6QoFzbrf

Comment: The form gets submitted as this is the default behavior of HTML5 button.
You can change that by setting [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type). Here is updated example - http://plnkr.co/edit/NZgRmAamj5yDzlCxjhV8?p=preview